# Error in compilation in opencv

Tags: linux, opencv, g++

I just installed opencv 2.4.0 . While compiling a sample code using

```
g++ -I/usr/include -L/usr/lib -lopencv_core.2.4.0 -lopencv_calib3d.2.4.0      -lopencv_imgproc.2.4.0 -lopencv_legacy.2.4.0 -lopencv_highgui.2.4.0 asd.cpp
```

I got the following errors

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_core.2.4.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_calib3d.2.4.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_imgproc.2.4.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_legacy.2.4.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_highgui.2.4.0
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where did you install it to?

Comment: I followed these instructionshttp://www.samontab.com/web/2012/06/installing-opencv-2-4-1-ubuntu-12-04-lts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use command line : locate opencv_core.2.4.0 to find path
add Path to your command